# Unit test fails when use try/catch

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I need to test that exactly Argument Exception is caugtht. Is it really possible to understand that exception in method is caugtht?

```
    public JsonResult Create(TeamViewModel teamViewModel)
    {
        JsonResult result = null;
            try
            {
                // here exception throws
                var domainTeam = teamViewModel.ToDomain();
                  ...
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ex.Message);
                result = this.Json(this.ModelState);
            }           

        return result;
    }
```

My Unit test for this method:

```
 public void Create_InvalidTeamAchievements_ArgumentExceptionThrown()
 {
    Exception exception = null;
    string invalidAchievements = CreateInvalidTeamAchievements();

    // Arrange
    var viewModel = new TeamMvcViewModelBuilder().WithAchievements(invalidAchievements).Build();
    var sut = _kernel.Get<TeamsController>();

    // Act
    try
    {
        sut.Create(viewModel);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        exception = ex;
    }

    // Assert
    VerifyExceptionThrown(exception, string.Format(Resources.ValidationTeamAchievements, 
                Constants.Team.MAX_ACHIEVEMENTS_LENGTH));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are testing it in wrong way. Functionality should be tested to not throw exception as you already have caught exception inside Create Method. Rather you should Assert that `JsonResult`  containing your `ModelState` should have error in it in case exception was raised in `Create` method.

Comment: To this point, having a try catch is typically a big no no in your unit test.  If you want to test that an exception is thrown simply add the [ExpectedException] attribute.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx